# How to keep unique row names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I have a list of traits in a column like below:

```
df <- read.table(text="
colID
A_14_EVB
A_14_gEVB
A_14_adj_p_r
B_14_EVB
B_14_adj_p_r
C_16_adj_p_r
C_16_gEVB
D_17_16_gEVB
D_00_87_adj_p_r", header = TRUE)
```

I want to keep only a single entry per suffix, which means that if there are three times A_14 with extensions _EVB, _gEVB, and _adj_p_r, I want to keep only `A_14_EVB` and also the same for the other entries like `B_14_EVB`, `C_16_gEVB`. The other entries with only one unique extension will stay the same. Can you please suggest a generic solution to do that in R?

I am looking for the following output:

```
colID
A_14_EVB
B_14_EVB
C_16_gEVB
D_17_16_gEVB
D_00_87_adj_p_r
```

Some names are like Height_14_20_EBV, Size_C_18_adj_p_r, Weight_16_C_18_gEVB, etc. So the length of the names varies considerably. I am actually looking for a generic code to handle this issue.

Comment: I think you may be confusing suffix and prefix, but overall it would be great if you could show the desired output from your table above - that will help a lot with the logic.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to subset the data, the perhaps this could work

```
df %>%
  group_by(prefix = gsub("([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*","\\1", colID)) %>% 
  slice_head(n=1)
```

This returns

```
  colID           prefix
  <chr>           <chr> 
1 A_14_EVB        A_14  
2 B_14_EVB        B_14  
3 C_16_adj_p_r    C_16  
4 D_00_87_adj_p_r D_00  
5 D_17_16_gEVB    D_17
```

This idea is to use a regular expression to grab the first two parts of the ID and then keep only one row per prefix

Comment: I have been peer pressued into adding `ungroup()` to my answers, so I must in turn peer pressure you 

Answer (score 2):

Its unclear in the question but if all the prefixes are the same length (here, I am assuming 4 characters, ie "X_00"), in base R you could use `substr()` and `duplicated` to [index] the dataset:

```
df[!duplicated(substr(df$colID, 1, 4)),]
# or 
df$colID[!duplicated(substr(df$colID, 1, 4))]

# [1] "A_14_EVB"        "B_14_EVB"        "C_16_adj_p_r"    "D_17_16_gEVB"    "D_00_87_adj_p_r"
```

Alternatively if you just focus on the extensions to allow for variable length names, you can use `gsub` in a similar fashion. Here, I defined the extensions of interest in your example data as `ext`:

```
ext <- c("EVB", "gEVB", "adj_p_r")

df$colID[!duplicated(gsub(paste(ext, collapse = "|"), "", df$colID))]

# [1] "A_14_EVB"        "B_14_EVB"        "C_16_adj_p_r"    "D_17_16_gEVB"    "D_00_87_adj_p_r"
```

Comment: smart idea! (+1)

Comment: Not really. I have long names in some cases. So something generic is needed. But the solution is cool. thank you.

Comment: @AnikDutta gotcha - could you edit your question to more accurately describe what's going on?

Comment: @jpsmith Yes, I have updated my question. The length of the names is variable.

Comment: @AnikDutta I get the names are variable, but what I’m confused about is what makes something a prefix or not

Comment: @jpsmith maybe I wrote it wrong. It should not be treated as a prefix literally, but rather filtering based on the EBV, gEVB, etc. and just keeping only a single entry.

Comment: @AnikDutta ok see edit and let me know if that is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(group = str_extract(colID, "^[A-Z]_[0-9_]+")) |>
  summarise(colID = first(colID), .by = group)
```

Output:

```
     group           colID
1    A_14_        A_14_EVB
2    B_14_        B_14_EVB
3    C_16_    C_16_adj_p_r
4 D_17_16_    D_17_16_gEVB
5 D_00_87_ D_00_87_adj_p_r
```

Comment: It looks like some IDs contain underscores within them, such as `D_17_16` and `D_00_87`. This still should work if no two groups overlap at the second value (when delimited by `_`), but would drop a group if, for example, `D_00_87` and `D_00_99` were supposed to be unique groups. Ideally the string would have a unique delimiter between group and suffix in the first place.